# Php array list with Spilitted String

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to uses this Function :

```
 array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

How can i use Explode and Put result in Array ?

For example , 'Hello i am here'

Then , i want to Loop this array to its Full Size , get each Words in a String while it has More Elements ,

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: i didnt tried for Now , i am looking How can i achieve it

Comment: you had a look at the doc? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: You achieve it by trying probably.

Comment: @lhsan , i have a String in DataBase : 'Hello i am here' i want to get this String , Split this String by " "(Space) then Put all words into an Array , then i want to Loop this array and get all these words in each String

Comment: @Rogier Yes Sure , jeroen i Can Not try Something i dont know ...

Comment: Everything we Post here get DownVote ... :/

Comment: @Nikita - read the examples on the PHP documentation page, and try what they suggest with your string

Comment: @Nikita. If i dont understand something in the docs i will usually search for "****** examples", in your case "php explode examples". 99/100 you will find an example, which you can then learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
 array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )
```

> Split the given string by a regular expression.

Try this:

```
<?php
// split the phrase by any number of commas or space characters,
// which include " ", \r, \t, \n and \f
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", "hypertext language, programming");
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hypertext
    [1] => language
    [2] => programming
)
```

Comment: but How can i Check/Compare these World in Array if its Equals to 'Hello' for Example

Comment: while $array_hasmoreElement $Word = $array Something like this

Comment: SON OF BITCH who DownVote & Blocked All My Post , this System is UNFAIR WTF Anyone can DownVote Anything , Me Too i Will DownVote Anything , WTF you Want ???? my Post arnt Clear Enough ????

Comment: Can SomeOne UpVote My Post in the Same Way(UnFair) somes Peoples DownVOted My Post ?

Answer (score 0):

explode() function needs a $delemeter to break the string into several parts and store each part in array. It cannot be blank so your requirement cannot be acheived.

However you can try the following

$string = "Hello I am here";

If you want your array to be array('H','e','l','l','o','I','a','m','h','e','r','e'). Then here's a solution.

```
$resultArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
    $val = substr($string,$i,1);
    if($val!=' ')
        $resultArray[] = $val;
}
print_r($resultArray); // expected output
```

Comment: Sorry for the Mistake , i want Each Words 'Hello' 'i' 'Am' 'Here' , the String should be Splited by " "

Comment: Can SomeOne UpVote My Post in the Same Way(UnFair) somes Peoples DownVOted My Post ?